# Why were my banana muffins hard?

Tags: baking, muffins

The top of my muffin came out a little hard, and the whole muffin wasn't soft enough. My recipe had

```
3 cups flour
1 teaspoon baking soda
1 teaspoon salt
1/2 teaspoon baking powder
2 cup sugar
1 cup of vegetable oil
3 large eggs
1 tablespoon vanilla extract
4 ripe bananas.
```

Comment: Without seeing the recipe for clarification, it's a little tough to say. But it sounds like the oven temperature was too high, and they were baked for too long. Would you mind posting the recipe?

Comment: Baking time and temperature? Did you mix for a long time? Were they overbrowned or just too hard?

Answer (score 5):

In the given recipe, assuming generously that the bananas came out to 1 3/4 c, the total water is:

```
Approximately 12 oz from banana
Approximately 3 oz from eggs
```

With three cups of flour, assuming a 4.5 oz cup of flour, this is a ratio of 0.9 : 1 flour to water by weight.

Compare to a similar banana muffin recipe (this one from the [Food Network](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/food-network-kitchens/banana-muffins-recipe/index.html)):

```
2 1/2 cups unbleached all-purpose flour
1/2 teaspoon baking soda
3/4 cup dark brown sugar
1/4 teaspoon ground cinnamon
2 cups smashed bananas (about 4 to 6 bananas)
1/2 cup vegetable oil
1/2 cup milk
2 large eggs, at room temperature
1/8 teaspoon fine salt
1/2 teaspoon pure vanilla extract
3/4 cups chopped walnuts
```

The water content of this recipe is approximately:

```
 4 oz from milk
 2 oz from eggs
 14 oz from banana
```

Again, with a 4.5 oz cup of flour, the flour to water ratio is 0.56 : 1 flour to water by weight.

Note that the recipe used has a much higher flour : water ratio, making a much drier and  stiffer batter.  It sounds like nearly a dough.  It also has a relatively huge amount of sugar and oil.

My guess is the original recipe was not well designed and tested.   It is highly likely that:

- The recipe you have used simply has a very low hydration of the flour, which would contribute to poor texture
- The low hydration encouraged overmixing, which developed gluten and created toughness

You have not indicated time or temperature or muffin size, but it is also likely that they were overbaked.

I would suggest finding a quality recipe as a base.  Also, chocolate chips are great in banana muffins, but that is a separate issue.